# Schengen Visa Photo requirement - conflict

Tags: online-resources, schengen-visas, applications, photography

I visited Schengen visa photo requirement on their official website. I found the photo size to be 35–40mm in width. On some other websites, I have seen the photo requirement to be 35 - 45 mm , 32 - 45mm. People who have successfully applied for Schengen visa recently, what is the photo size pls ?

Thank you.

Comment: The one that appears more widely-used. I'd bet for a larger size hoping they would cut excess 5mm on their own, if any.

Comment: Depending on where you are try and find the website of the local embassy of the country you want to get a visa to. They're likely to have information about local photographers that know and abide by the EU photo requirements. The website of the Dutch embassy in Tel Aviv for example lists a local photographer that they know abides by the EU photo requirements.

Comment: @Ricky101 For clarity, which ‘official website’ are you referring to, and which country are you applying to?

Comment: Thank you for the answers. This is the official website I was referring to https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/required_documents_en   . I'm applying to France

Answer (score 1):

From your previous questions it looks like you’re applying to France from India. The official website accessed via the VFSGlobal website is https://france-visas.gouv.fr/web/france-visas Under FAQs, the answer regarding photo format states:

The picture must be recent and conform to reality. The photo should be 35 mm wide and 45 mm high. The size of the face should be 32 to 36 mm (70 to 80% of the picture) from chin to forehead (excluding hair).